# Why bootstrap has java script , jquery and ajax file as dependency when we import cdn links

Tags: bootstrap-modal

Bootstrap is ready-made styles with responsive controlls then why we need to import jquery and ajax files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap supports default stylesheets not to jquery-min. When you download bootstrap package from its website, you can see it includes only css folder, js folder and font folder. In it's js folder you can see it doesn't include jquery-min.js. So. we need to include it manually.

Comment: then why in tutorials and all saying to import both files which i given bellow<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>